# Running npm install after pulling from GitHub, an error appears instructing me to fix an upstream dependency issue

Tags: gatsby

[image]

I just need to run the project, it was created a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try delete node-modules and package-lock.json and re-run npm i.
Otherwise you can try installing/upgrading manually @emotion/styled:
`npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled`
https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/styled

Comment: Thank you for your response, I started the project over.